# K&R exercise 1-19 remade for a file to be read as argument

Tags: c, kernighan-and-ritchie

I'm reviewing K&R exercises from the beginning and I'm extending everything that is meant to be in stdin as a file, that is meant to be passed as argv. The point is that in this exercise a function doesn't work properly, I think it's some problem with strlen, but I just can't figure out what it really is. The function reverses the lines of the file correctly (apparently), but I always get the first two chars of the first line in every reversed string.
"Write a function reverse that reverses the character
string s. Use it to write a program that reverses its input a line at a time".

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
const unsigned MAXLINE = 10000;
char* reverse(char string[])
{
    char rev[MAXLINE];
    int i, j;
    for (i = strlen(string)-1, j = 0; i >= 0, j < strlen(string); --i, ++j)
            rev[j] = string[i];
    return rev;
}
unsigned fgetline(char s[], unsigned lim, FILE *file)
{
    unsigned i;
    char c;
    for (i = 0; (c = fgetc(file)) != EOF && c != '\n'; ++i)
            s[i] = c;
    if (c == '\n')
    {
            s[i] = c;
            ++i;
    }
    s[i] = '\0';
    return i;
}
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    FILE *input = fopen(argv[1], "r");
    char line[MAXLINE];
    unsigned len = 0;
    if (argc != 2 || !input)
            puts("INSERT VALID INPUT FILE");
    else
    {
            while ((len = fgetline(line, MAXLINE, input)) > 0)
            {
                    printf("%s\n", reverse(line));
                    putchar('\n');
            }
            fclose(input);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You are returning a pointer to a local buffer in `reverse()`, so I'm actually surprised this works at all. Also, you forgot to null-terminate `rev` before returning.

Comment: When compiling, always enable all warnings.  (for gcc, at a minimum use: '-Wall -Wextra -pedantic')  The compiler will then tell you of numerous syntax problems with the posted code.   After fixing those problems, suggest using a debugger, like gdb, (in gcc, use the '-ggdb' parameter in both the compile and link step so gdb outputs are very readable) and step through the code

Comment: you can also reverse the string in place. Just swaping the `chars`. You are not making sure that the lines read by `fgetline` fit in `line`.

Comment: regarding this line: 'FILE *input = fopen(argv[1], "r");' do not access command line arguments until after checking argc to assure the argument exists.

Comment: the function: fgetc() returns a int, EOF is an int, so the line: 'char c;' should be 'int c;'

Comment: in function fgetline() in the 'for' statement, for robustness, need to add to second parameter: 'i < (lim-1)'

Comment: I null terminated the string and it works except for the fact that I have one extra char at the beginning af all lines from second line on. Could you explain me in detail what you mean by "returning a pointer to a local buffer in reverse()" ? How would you fix that?

Comment: @GiorgioDT `rev` is a local variable, and as any other local variables, it is destroyed once the function returns. By returning `rev` you are returning a pointer to a buffer that is destroyed when the function exits - so by the time you try to use it, it's undefined behavior because you don't own that memory anymore. Just allocate the buffer in `main()` and pass it to `reverse()`, or reverse the line in-place.

Comment: What if I make rev[MAXLINE] an external variable? so the memory remains allocated even after the function executes its task

Answer (score 3):

The char string 'rev' loses scope after the call and thus is undefined in behavior.  Consider passing rev in as a parameter to reverse().

Comment: Right, you need to null-terminate the reversed string as well.

Comment: I'm sorry but I didn't get it. What do you mean with passing rev in as a parameter to reverse, precisely? What should it return then?

Comment: create a variable char revline[MAXLINE] in main.  Then call reverse(line, revline);.  It need not return anything (perhaps success/fail).  It should put the results in revline.

Answer (score 1):

I ran the following code.

I compiles cleanly

it uses a good logical order for setting up the operation

it clears out any buffers before using them, which
amongst other things assures all strings are terminated.

I ran it against its' own source file.

I do not see any problems in the resulting outputs

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>  // exit(), EXIT_FAILURE
#include <string.h>

#define MAXLINE  (10000)

void reverse(char src[], char dest[])
{
    size_t i;
    size_t j = 0;

    memset( dest, '\0', MAXLINE);

    for (i = strlen(src)-1; i != 0; --i, ++j)
            dest[j] = src[i];
}


unsigned fgetline(char dest[], FILE *file)
{
    unsigned i;
    int c;
    memset( dest, '\0', MAXLINE);

    for (i = 0; i < (MAXLINE-1) && (c = fgetc(file)) != EOF && c != '\n'; ++i)
            dest[i] = c;

    if (c == '\n')
    {
            dest[i] = c;
            ++i;
    }

    dest[i] = '\0';
    return i;
}


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    if( argc != 2 )
    {
        printf( "USAGE: %s <inputFileName>\n", argv[0]);
        exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
    }

    // implied else, right number of command line parameters

    FILE *input = NULL;
    if( NULL == (input = fopen(argv[1], "r") ) )
    { // then fopen failed
        perror( "fopen for input file failed");
        exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
    }

    // implied else, fopen successful

    char inputLine[MAXLINE] = {'\0'};
    char outputLine[MAXLINE] = {'\0'};

    while (fgetline(inputLine, input))
    {
        reverse(inputLine, outputLine);
        printf("%s\n", outputLine);
        putchar('\n');
    }

    fclose(input);

    return 0;
}
```